# Hooking up a generateSrc gradle task before multiple"compile..." tasks

Tags: gradle

### Background

I have made a gradle plugin that generates thrift sources.
The sources needs to be generated before the java compiler is run.
Up until now it just did:

```
project.compileJava.dependsOn 'generateThrift'
```

### The problem

I now use kotlin in multiple projects using the plugin, but now a `clean build` fails because `compileKotlin` runs before `generateThrift`

### The question

Is it possible to have the `generateThrift` task run, before any (also future) compile taks is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
project.tasks.withType(AbstractCompile).forEach{
    it.dependsOn 'generateThrift'
}
```